# Can't install an Ubuntu Desktop edition (20.04, 22.04, 22.10) in a VMWare virtual machine

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, installation

I can't install a recent Ubuntu Desktop guest OS in my VMWare ESXI 7.0.0 (Build 16324942).

Each time I try, the installation process crashes on the "Where are you?" screen (when you have to choose the meridian in which you are), and the window is closed.

Then I can see the Ubuntu OS which were started from the ISO file (this VM is not installed in the VM. It is he "try Ubuntu" OS).

This is my VM's configuration :

> CPU : 2
> Core per socket : 2 (sockets : 1)
> CPU hot plug : décoché
> Reservation : No
> Limit : unlimited
> Parts : Normal
> Material virtualisation : No
> IOMMU : No
> Performance counter : No
> Afinity planification

> Memory :
> RAM : 8Go
> Reservation : No
> All guest memory reservation : No
> Limit : unlimited
> Parts : Normal
> Hotplug Memory Connexion : No

> Hard disk 1 : 96 Go
> Max size  : 2 To
> Type : Static provisionning, late reset
> Disc file : [VMs]CEN-Ubuntu2204-OdkCentral/CEN-Ubuntu2204-OdkCentral.vmdk
> Parts : normal
> Limit – IOPs : Unilimited
> Controller location : SCSI 0 Controller / SCSI (0:0)
> Disc mode : Dependent
> Share : No

> SCSI 0 Controller : LSI Logic Parallel
> SCSI Bus sharing : No

> SATA 0 controller : Nothing
>
> USB 1 controller : USB 3.1

> Network adapter 1 : VM Network
> Connected : Yes
> State : « Connect when power on » Yes
> Adapter type : VMXNET 3
> MAC address : automatic
>
> CD/DVD drive : Databank ISO file (Ubuntu installation)
> Controler location : SATA 0 controller / SATA (0/0)

> Video card : default
> Screens : 1
> Whole video memory : 4 Mo
> 3D graphics : No
> 3D rendering : Automatic

> Security devices : Not configured
> SGX : Disabled
> Enclave page cache size : 0 Mo
> Launch control configuration : Unlocked
> Restrictions : Some operations and features are restricted (not compatible with SGX : vMotion, Fault tolerance, Suspending a VM, Taking a snapshot of a VM)

> VM Options :
> General options :
> Name : CEN-Ubuntu2204-OdkCentral
> Config. File : [VMs] CEN-Ubuntu2204-OdkCentral/CEN-Ubuntu2204-OdkCentral.vmx
> Working directory : [VMs] CEN-Ubuntu2204-OdkCentral
> Guest OS : Linux Guest OS
> version : Ubuntu Linux (64 bits)

> VMWare Remote Control Options :
> Guest OS lockdown : No
> Max sessions number : no limit

> VMWare Tools :
> Alimentation :
>
> 1. Stop guest OS
> 2. Guest OS standby
> 3. Power on / resume

I tried with 20.04, 22.04 and 22.10 Ubuntu desktop versions. I could install an Ubuntu 22.04 server edition (with only command line), and I've got 3 VM running CENTOS (6 to 9), which were installed without a bug.

Does anyone know the compatibilities between ESXI and Ubuntu?  I tried to use the VMWare compatibility guide on the net https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/detail.php?deviceCategory=Software&productid=45909&testConfig=16&supRel=508,485,448,428,427,369,429,408,367,338,276,275,274,273, But I found no other guest OS compatibles than 2 Suse versions... strange

Has anyone experienced the same bug before? Thanks for advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit to quick on the send button sorry!
We were able to install 22.04 by removing the networkcard in vmware. However when we re-addeded after install we have several crashes of gnome packages. Like calculator, whoopsie, gnome-initial-setup, fwupd,...

So any idea on what the issue is or how to solve it would be helpfull!

Update 11/01/2023:
We installed ubuntu desktop 18 without any issues and then just upgraded to 20 and 22 in GUI interface.

Comment: Thank you very much @Nicolas ! I post my question on VMWare forum and found this workaround yesterday. With the network card disconnected, the installation is straightforward. I've got problems with apt when adding a repo, etc... (maybe the same bugs as yours?) but the OS is installed. It's a first step! \o/

Comment: Hey, it indeeds sounds like the same issue. I did have some some issues installing gitlab and had to download the package to install it. But that could be a gitlab issue.
I did find a bugreport on the ubuntu site on it, but also no solution. [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1976585)
When you start the calculator does it also crash?
Hopefully a solution can be found.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Desktop needs a dual-core CPU, give that a try.

Comment: Thank you for your very fast answer. Unfortunately, I tried with 2 CPU (1 per socket or 2 per socket), but the result is the same. But I keep this config! Thanks

Comment: It's really odd as I have an Ubuntu server running on ESXi 7 right in front of me - maybe show ALL of the VM's settings in your question, might be useful.

Comment: Yes, I managed to install an Ubuntu server. It's just the desktop version whose installation crashes. I prefer to install the desktop version, it would be more comfortable for me. But I will edit my question and show all parameters.

Comment: Is the VM connected to a virtual switch with connection to the internet ?

Comment: Hello, no I don't think (if I understand what a virtual switch is...). The VM is on a VMWare, connected to the internet via a physical switch and a VPN.